# Can Nginx serve https only if the Flask user is authenticated?

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I am running my Flask project behind an nginx server.  I already set certificates for https.  Is there a way for only Flask logged in users to get https while anonymous users get http?

Comment: Why would you possibly want to use http instead of https? That seems strange, especially in the light of recent events.